# Tkinter entry and button combined function doesn't work in other function

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I created a function calling a GUI having several entries and a button.
If I push the button then the values on entries will be returned on the function.

```
def date_time_gui ():
    win = tk.Tk()
    win.title('powered by Python') # win title
    win.geometry('700x400') # size of win

    # add label on the win
    label = tk.Label(win, 
        text='type the heaving datetime and out water datetime',
        font = ('Arial Bold',25)
        )
    label.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.05, anchor = 'n')

    # label and entry for heaving datetime
    heaving_label = tk.Label(win,
        text='type heaving datetime',
        font = ('Arial Bold', 15)
        )
    heaving_label.place(relx = 0.1, rely = 0.3, anchor = 'w')

    h_year_label = tk.Label(win, text='YEAR (4 digits) :')
    h_year_label.place(relx = 0.1, rely = 0.4, anchor = 'w')
    h_year = tk.Entry(win, fg='black', width = 5)
    h_year.place(relx = 0.3, rely = 0.4, anchor = 'w')


    h_month_label = tk.Label(win, text='MONTH (2 digits) :')
    h_month_label.place(relx = 0.1, rely = 0.5, anchor = 'w')
    h_month = tk.Entry(win, fg='black', width = 5)
    h_month.place(relx = 0.3, rely = 0.5, anchor = 'w')


    h_date_label = tk.Label(win, text='DATE (2 digits) :')
    h_date_label.place(relx = 0.1, rely = 0.6, anchor = 'w')
    h_date = tk.Entry(win, fg='black', width = 5)
    h_date.place(relx = 0.3, rely = 0.6, anchor = 'w')


    h_hour_label = tk.Label(win, text='HOUR (24h, 2 digits) :')
    h_hour_label.place(relx = 0.1, rely = 0.7, anchor = 'w')
    h_hour = tk.Entry(win, fg='black', width = 5)
    h_hour.place(relx = 0.3, rely = 0.7, anchor = 'w')

    h_minute_label = tk.Label(win, text='MINUTE (2 digits) :')
    h_minute_label.place(relx = 0.1, rely = 0.8, anchor = 'w')
    h_minute = tk.Entry(win, fg='black', width = 5)
    h_minute.place(relx = 0.3, rely = 0.8, anchor = 'w')



    # label and entry for out water datetime
    outwater_label = tk.Label(win,
        text='type out water datetime',
        font = ('Arial Bold', 15)
        )
    outwater_label.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.3, anchor = 'w')

    o_year_label = tk.Label(win, text='YEAR (4 digits) :')
    o_year_label.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.4, anchor = 'w')
    o_year = tk.Entry(win, fg='black', width = 5)
    o_year.place(relx = 0.7, rely = 0.4, anchor = 'w')


    o_month_label = tk.Label(win, text='MONTH (2 digits) :')
    o_month_label.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5, anchor = 'w')
    o_month = tk.Entry(win, fg='black', width = 5)
    o_month.place(relx = 0.7, rely = 0.5, anchor = 'w')


    o_date_label = tk.Label(win, text='DATE (2 digits) :')
    o_date_label.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.6, anchor = 'w')
    o_date = tk.Entry(win, fg='black', width = 5)
    o_date.place(relx = 0.7, rely = 0.6, anchor = 'w')


    o_hour_label = tk.Label(win, text='HOUR (24h, 2 digits) :')
    o_hour_label.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.7, anchor = 'w')
    o_hour = tk.Entry(win, fg='black', width = 5)
    o_hour.place(relx = 0.7, rely = 0.7, anchor = 'w')

    o_minute_label = tk.Label(win, text='MINUTE (2 digits) :')
    o_minute_label.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.8, anchor = 'w')
    o_minute = tk.Entry(win, fg='black', width = 5)
    o_minute.place(relx = 0.7, rely = 0.8, anchor = 'w')

    def run_func ():
        global heaving
        global outwater
        heaving = h_year.get()+'.'+h_month.get()+'.'+h_date.get()+' '+h_hour.get()+' '+h_minute.get()
        outwater = o_year.get()+'.'+o_month.get()+'.'+o_date.get()+' '+o_hour.get()+' '+o_minute.get()
        print('here')
        win.destroy()
        print('there')
        return heaving, outwater
    print('else')
    button = ttk.Button(win, text = 'run', command = run_func)  
    button.place(relx = 0.8, rely = 0.9, anchor = 'w')
    print('this')
    win.mainloop()
    print('where')
    return heaving, outwater
```

It works if I run it with the following code within the same script.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    h, o = date_time_gui()
    print(h,o)
```

it printed out h, o which are the return values of the function date_time_gui

However, if I apply this function to other definition like

```
def other_def():
    ## some code
    heaving_datetime, out_water_datetime = date_time_gui()
```

It just stops working.

I wanted to check which line in the date_time_gui is the problem, so I printed out 'there', 'where' etc.

When I run the other_def, it printed out
else
this
here
there

and then didn't print out 'where'

I really don't know what is the problem as the date_time_gui function itself works well.
It doesn't work when I apply this to other functions.

- maybe, to run the other_def I made a gui having checkbox to run the other_def.
  So, if I check the other_def function on the gui and hit the run button, the gui will be destroyed and other_def will be run. And the new gui for date_time_gui pop-up and hit the run button, then gui destroyed and stop working.

Comment: You said "it just stops working". What does that mean? Does the program crash? Do you get an exception?

Comment: if it doesn't print "where", this should mean, the `mainloop()` is still running and the GUI didn't exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a **tkinter** window

- Calling the **loop()** method activates the tkinter message pump and will stop the linear python code until the window is closed
- You can exit the loop by manually closing the window or call **quit()** from your code.

In your case, calling `win.mainloop()` stopped the linear script.

You can exit the loop by adding `win.quit()` to the `run_func` function.

Try this code:

```
    def run_func ():
        global heaving
        global outwater
        heaving = h_year.get()+'.'+h_month.get()+'.'+h_date.get()+' '+h_hour.get()+' '+h_minute.get()
        outwater = o_year.get()+'.'+o_month.get()+'.'+o_date.get()+' '+o_hour.get()+' '+o_minute.get()
        print('here')
        win.destroy()
        print('there')
        win.quit()   # exit gui loop
        return heaving, outwater  # not needed
    
    print('else')
    button = ttk.Button(win, text = 'run', command = run_func)  
    button.place(relx = 0.8, rely = 0.9, anchor = 'w')
    print('this')
    win.mainloop()  # python code stops here until window closed
    print('where')
    heaving, outwater = 3,4  # for testing
    return heaving, outwater

if __name__ == "__main__":
    h, o = date_time_gui()
    print(h,o)
```

Output

```
else
this
here
there
where
3 4
```